# Vector space and form?

Tags: classical-mechanics

What is the significance of equipping the vector space with a form? For instance a symplectic space has a symlectic two form? Why does it need it + what does having it allow/benifit us?

Comment: To relate a vector space to its dual vector space I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bilinear forms on a vector space equip the vector space with a geometry. If all you have is a vector space, then you can't speak of angles or lengths of vectors. If you have a bilinear form (such as an inner product, or a symplectic form) then you can speak of various geometric concepts. So, roughly, vector space + a form = richer geometry.